# Is $\langle S, \oplus, \otimes\rangle$ a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Here
$$
S=\left\{\begin{Vmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{Vmatrix}:x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n\right\}
$$
and operations defined by equalities
$$
\alpha\otimes\begin{Vmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{Vmatrix}=\begin{Vmatrix}\alpha x_1\\ \alpha x_2\end{Vmatrix}\qquad
$$
$$
\begin{Vmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{Vmatrix}\oplus \begin{Vmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\end{Vmatrix}=
\begin{Vmatrix}x_1+y_2\\ 0\end{Vmatrix}
$$
**My question:** Is $\langle S, \oplus, \otimes\rangle$ a vector space?

Comment: Please put the entire question in the body of the post. Try and tell us what you tried or didn't try to do.

Comment: Also, please don't put things like "Prove your answer" in the title. The title is meant to show at a glance what the question is about. When you choose a title, imagine how it will look in the question list on the main page.

Comment: Is your addition commutative?

Answer (score 7):

One axiom vector spaces must follow is the existence of a zero vector. You need some element $\vec{0}$ for which $\vec{v}+\vec{0}=\vec{v}$ for all $\vec{v}$. But if $x_2$ is non-zero, your addition operation makes this impossible. So it's not a vector space.